# How do i use 'auto' in C++ (C++0x)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-c++-2008

What do i have to do to this code to make it compile, it's braking around this line:

auto val = what.getObject();

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class CUP{
    public:
        void whatsHappening(){}
};

class MUG{
    public:
        void whatsHappening(){}
};

class CupThrower{
    public:
        CUP cp;
        CUP getObject(){ return cp;}
};

class MugThrower{
    public:
        MUG mg;
        MUG getObject(){return mg;}
};

template <typename T> void whatsHappening(T what){

    auto val = what.getObject(); //DOES NOT COMPILE
    val.whatsHappening();
}

int main(){
    CupThrower ct;
    MugThrower mt;
    whatsHappening(ct);
    whatsHappening(mt);
    return 0;
}
```

i am using VS2008 to compile.

Comment: Posting the actual error that you are getting would be helpful. Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: i am using VS2008 , the error is too long to post

Comment: VS2008 Doesn't support `auto`, move to VS2010 or GCC 4.4/4.5.

Comment: Why are you trying to use auto? Historically, auto has meant "treat this variable exactly as you would with no modifiers." Its only use was aesthetically, if you have a bunch of static this and extern that, you can say auto the other thing to make things line up...

Comment: or, did auto change its meaning at some point? That might break some code...

Comment: @Brian: Since the `auto` keyword in its original meaning hasn't been used in decades, the next C++ standard will recycle it giving it a new meaning. If you happen to know `var` in C# - that's going to be `auto` in C++.

Comment: @sbi that seems ... dangerous... why not just invent a new keyword? huh...

Comment: @Brian: Introducing new keywords always breaks some people's code. OTOH, I can't imagine that there would be code out there using `auto` in its original (and redundant) meaning that someone actually wants to compile using the next-generation C++ compiler. I have first seen redefining `auto` suggested in c.l.c++.m about a decade ago, have seen it discussed a lot since, and have never ever heard of anyone who claimed their code would break if that was done. Can you suggest any new keyword with that trait?

Comment: I read somewhere that the committee checked hundreds of projects to see how they were using certain words, and in the case of `auto` they didn't find a single project that was making use of it for anything except testing compiler outputs.

Comment: @sbi: no it doesn't. Please study how the C committee dealt with this problem: the new keyword is like _bool which is not a permitted user space identifier so can't break anything. Then #include <bool.h> is used to #define bool _bool, also can't break anything unless you have a header bool.h, and then new program code can either use _bool in headers or #include <bool.h> as a late include in body files to enable "bool". A bit messy, but no breakage.

Comment: @Yttrill: Huh? If my code, using the `bool` as an identifier, includes your header, which tomorrow starts to include `<bool.h>`, my code will be broken tomorrow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Auto isn't supported in VS2008. Use VS2010 and later versions, or another compiler supporting this feature.

Comment: It was the compile version, i dont have vs2010 but i tried with gcc 4.4* and it worked. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

Auto is a feature only present in C++0x and, therefore, isn't enabled by default in most (if not all) the compilers. Have you used the appropriate options in your compiler to enable it?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2008 to compile, what do i have to enable to make this work?

Comment: @Loud:  You have to enable "upgrade to Visual Studio 2010"  :-)

Comment: actually, no. Auto is available in the C standard (and thus I'm pretty sure C++) The only thing is that it does absolutely nothing. It defines a local variable as having local scope... um... yay?

Comment: @Brian: Since the `auto` in its original form keyword hasn't been seen in the wild for decades, the next C++ standard has redefined its meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Others have said that `auto` isn't in VC9, which is sort-of true.  `auto` doesn't mean in the current C++ Standard what it means in C++0x.  In the current Standard, it effectively means nothing useful.  Long story short, you can't use `auto` the way you're trying to use it here.

But there is an alternative.  In this code:

```
template <typename T> void whatsHappening(T what){

    auto val = what.getObject(); //DOES NOT COMPILE
    val.whatsHappening();
}
```

...the problem you're having is `val` is of an unknown type.  If `T` is `CupThrower`, then `getObject()` returns a CUP.  Likewise, for `MugThrower`, `getObject()` returns a `MUG`. The way your code is written, you have no way to know the type returned by `getObject()` based solely on the type of `T`.  So the solution is to add a way to know it.  Try this:

```
class CupThrower{
    public:
        typedef CUP ObjectType;
        ObjectType cp;
        ObjectType getObject(){ return cp;}
};

class MugThrower{
    public:
        typedef MUG ObjectType;
        ObjectType mg;
        ObjectType getObject(){return mg;}
};
```

Now the type returned by `getObject()` is part of the enclosing class.  You can change your `whatsHappening()` function to use this information:

```
template <typename T> void whatsHappening(T what){

    T::ObjectType val = what.getObject(); //DOES COMPILE!
    val.whatsHappening();
}
```

And all is right with the world again.

Comment: that's well and good but i'm trying to learn how to use implicitly typed variables with c++0x, this doesnt answer my question.

Comment: You need to change that to `typename T::ObjectType val = ...`

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't compile because you're trying to deal with zero-sized non-function objects.

Edit:
Works fine for me in VS2010.

Comment: i'm not too sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Neither am I, but I'm pretty sure this isn't the reason why your code isn't compiling.

Comment: DeadMG makes this kind of stuff up as he goes along - ignore.

Comment: @John, it isn't the reason at all. Heck, it's not even possible to have a zero-sized object in standard C++.

Comment: One of us at least attempted to post a useful suggestion. One of us just trolled.