# How does c++ (c++0x) handle implicitly typed variables?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn how to use implicitly typed variables in c++.

Should i be using 'auto' from C++0x? If so how?

Can some one provide me with a simple example or a good tutorial on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924901/how-do-i-use-auto-in-c-c0x

Comment: Look for discussion of the `var` keyword in C#; a lot of the arguments for and against will be the same.

Comment: To provide a link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c has discussion of the `var` keyword in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto x = f();
```

The type of `x` will be whatever `f()` returns.

Comment: also x has to be cast back into the type f() returns :)

Comment: @LoudNPossiblyRight: I have no idea what you are trying to say. (Whatever interpretation I can come up with seems wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this explanation from Bjarne Stroustrup himself: [auto -- deduction of a type from an initializer](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#auto).